# Создать в case объект с одним и тем же именем, но с разными(в зависимости от переменной) классами

Tags: c#, ооп, классы

Суть в том, что есть программа с реализованными простыми алгоритмами шифрования, для удобства там используется абстрактный класс, от которого наследуются другие алгоритмы шифрования, соответственно нужные методы с одинаковым названием есть у объектов любого класса шифрования. Задача состоит в том, чтобы обеспечить возможность инициализации объекта класса с именем "А", но в зависимости от выбора алгоритма шифрования создавать его от разных классов.

```
switch (checkedButton.Text)
        {
            case "Caesar": Caesar A = new Caesar(textBox3.Text, alpha, textBox1.Text);
                break;
            case "Tritemius": Tritemius A = new Tritemius(textBox3.Text, alpha, textBox1.Text);
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BaseClass A = null;
switch (checkedButton.Text)
{
  case "Caesar":
    A = new Caesar(textBox3.Text, alpha, textBox1.Text);
    break;
  case "Tritemius":
    A = new Tritemius(textBox3.Text, alpha, textBox1.Text);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Для вашей задачи хорошо подходит шаблон Фабрика:

```
public static class EncryptionAlgorythmFactory {
    public static EncryptionAlgorythm CreateAlgorythmImpl(string name, string param1, string param2, string param3) {
        switch (name) {
            case "Caesar": return new Caesar(param1, param2, param3);
            case "Tritemius": return new Tritemius(param1, param2, param3);
            default: throw new ArgumentException("name");
        }
    }
}
```

Почитать про шаблоны проектирования можно здесь: [Паттерны проектирования в C# и .NET](https://metanit.com/sharp/patterns/). Но лучше всего найти вот такую книгу: [Приемы объектно-ориентированного проектирования. Паттерны проектирования](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2457392/)